# face_recognition and pytorch module conflict

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, streamlit, face-recognition

```
import os, pathlib
import streamlit as st
import os, datetime, json, sys, pathlib, shutil
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st
import cv2
import face_recognition
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.nn import Linear, Conv2d, BatchNorm1d, BatchNorm2d, PReLU, ReLU, Sigmoid, AdaptiveAvgPool2d, Sequential, Module
COLOR_DARK  = (0, 0, 153)
COLOR_WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
def BGR_to_RGB(image_in_array):
    return cv2.cvtColor(image_in_array, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
def main():
    ###################################################
    st.sidebar.header("About")
    st.sidebar.info("This webapp gives a demo of Visitor Monitoring "
                    "Webapp using 'Face Recognition' and Streamlit")
    ##################################################
    ## Reading Camera Image
    img_file_buffer = st.camera_input("Take a picture")

    if img_file_buffer is not None:
        bytes_data = img_file_buffer.getvalue()

        # convert image from opened file to np.array
        image_array         = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(bytes_data,
                                                            np.uint8),
                                            cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        image_array_copy    = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(bytes_data, np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        # st.image(cv2_img)
        ## Saving Visitor History

        ## Validating Image
        # Detect faces in the loaded image
        max_faces   = 0
        rois        = []  # region of interests (arrays of face areas)

        ## To get location of Face from Image
        face_locations  = face_recognition.face_locations(image_array)
        ## To encode Image to numeric format
        encodesCurFrame = face_recognition.face_encodings(image_array,
                                                            face_locations)

        ## Generating Rectangle Red box over the Image
        for idx, (top, right, bottom, left) in enumerate(face_locations):
            # Save face's Region of Interest
            rois.append(image_array[top:bottom, left:right].copy())

            # Draw a box around the face and label it
            cv2.rectangle(image_array, (left, top), (right, bottom), COLOR_DARK, 2)
            cv2.rectangle(image_array, (left, bottom + 35), (right, bottom), COLOR_DARK, cv2.FILLED)
            font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
            cv2.putText(image_array, f"#{idx}", (left + 5, bottom + 25), font, .55, COLOR_WHITE, 1)

        ## Showing Image
        st.image(BGR_to_RGB(image_array), width=720)

        ## Number of Faces identified
        max_faces = len(face_locations)

        if max_faces > 0:
            col1, col2 = st.columns(2)

            # select selected faces in the picture
            face_idxs = col1.multiselect("Select face#", range(max_faces),
                                            default=range(max_faces))

            ## Filtering for similarity beyond threshold
            similarity_threshold = col2.slider('Select Threshold for Similarity',
                                                    min_value=0.0, max_value=1.0,
                                                    value=0.5)
                                            ## check for similarity confidence greater than this threshold

            flag_show = False

#######################################################
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
#######################################################
```

I'm not sure why my code crashes without any logs when I use the PyTorch module and the face_recognition module simultaneously. I haven't done any research beyond asking this question, but I've found that the code only runs if I import one of the modules at a time.

i wanted to create a streamlit application that able to take picture and detect the face encoding on it.